# Android Heap Memory Corruption Causing Application to Crash

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, crash, heap-memory

I have made an android app with a simple linear layout with an OnItemClickListener which invokes different activities for different items.
The problem I am facing is that The 1st activity called never gets destroyed/finished.
I tried explicitly finishing the activity with

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
         finish();

    }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I have also declared every activity in the Manifest with

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

But i am still being confronted with crashes.
The final error says

```
A/libc(8740): @@@ ABORTING: LIBC: HEAP MEMORY CORRUPTION IN dlfree
```

Please Help.

Comment: The problem is not in the code you show. Do you have bitmaps that you recycle, for instance?

Comment: Ya i use a texture bitmap that gets destroyed at the end of the activity